# CSS browser compatibility issues. Drop down menu works in both Firefox and Chrome but doesn't in IE

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following CSS in my project. The CSS rendering perfectly in chrome and Firefox but fails to work properly on IE. The drop down menu doesn't show at all on IE

```
body {
    background-color:white;
}
.nvbar ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
.nvbar:after{
  content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.nvbar li {
    float:left;
    width:11%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:6px solid white;
    position:relative;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0a0a0a), color-stop(100%, #0a0a0a));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0a0a0a ', endColorstr='#0a0a0a ', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
.nvbar li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
.nvbar li ul li {
    float:none;
    width:180%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:4px;
    border-top:2px solid white;
}
.nvbar a {
    /*font-family:Meiryo UI,verdana,san-serif;*/
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}
.arrow1 {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:7px solid black;
    position:relative;
    right:-70%;
}
.arrow2 {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:7px solid black;
    position:relative;
    right:-70%;
}
.sub1 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.sub2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.srvlist:hover .sub2 {
    visibility:visible;
}
.prjlst:hover .sub1 {
    visibility:visible;
}
.nvbar li:hover {
    background: #eb2139;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eb2139), color-stop(100%, #eb2139));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb2139', endColorstr='#eb2139', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The following is the aspx page its supposed to render. It doesn't even show on IE whereas it works just fine on FireFox and Chrome

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebBasedGenerator.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 219px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 213px;
            height: 61px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 145px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {}
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            text-align: left;
            width: 138px;
        }
        .auto-style13 {
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
            width: 138px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div class="nvbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">    </a></li>
<%--    <li class="prjlst"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <div class="sub1">
    <ul>
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
    <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>--%>
    <li class="srvlist"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <div class="sub2">
    <ul>
    <div class="arrow2"></div>
    <li><a href="Generator.aspx">Generate </a></li>
     <li><a href="TLGenerator.aspx">Generate (TL) </a></li>
      <li><a href="PubKey.aspx">Instrument PKey</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>
         <table style="width: 100%;">
             <tr>
                 <td class="auto-style2">
                     <table style="width: 100%;">
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style8" colspan="4"><img class="auto-style1" src="Logo_screen.bmp" /></td>
                             <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style9"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="5">
                                 <hr style="width: 667px" />
                             </td>
                             <td class="auto-style5" rowspan="4"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="14">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style6" colspan="2" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style5"></td>
                         </tr>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style6" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7">
                                 </td>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2">
                                 </td>
                             <td class="auto-style13">
                                 </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="5">
                                 <hr />
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>

                 <td>

                     &nbsp;</td>

             </table>

         </div>
        </div>
<div>

    &nbsp;</div>

    </form>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle

Comment: which version of IE giving a problem?>

Comment: product tab is not showing in IE9 because you have made a wrong comment style .. like this `<%--  --%>` In addition text is not fit in the boxes because you giving `width:11%` on class `.nvbar li `

Answer (score 0):

I've checked in IE11 and the dropdown works fine, even in IE9 I also tested however I cannot see the Products section on the IE9 because of wrong comments you have used in the HTML file.

Here is the Code you used, please check the HTML comments are in wrong manner. In addition I've found a `width` problem in `.nvbar li` you should remove the `width:11%` because of this width the text is not fit inside the black box.

See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kemoxabu/1/edit)** First.

```
<%--    <li class="prjlst"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <div class="sub1">
    <ul>
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
    <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>--%>
```

Comment: Hi @Kheema Pandey, i'd start out by saying thanks. However, the Products 1-4 was commented out intentionally. i'm more concerned about the following part which doesnt work on IE 8 or later..... <li><a href="LicenseGenerator.aspx">Generate License</a></li>
     <li><a href="TLLicenseGenerator.aspx">Generate (TL) License</a></li>
      <li><a href="PubKey.aspx">Instrument PKey</a></li>

Comment: I've tested it with IE tester tool a Micrsoft product. and dropdown works fine in IE8 and IE9 well.

Comment: Hi again @Kheema Pandey, do you have any clues why I'm experiencing the problem then? I've deployed it to the server on the intranet and trust me buddy it doesn't work after testing it on 2 different systems

Comment: Its also really hard for me to check on IE8, previously I used to use `Browser stack` http://www.browserstack.com . but now i cannot test on it anymore.

Comment: I've tested it on IE 8 and 11 and sadly doesn't work still :-(

Comment: is that work for you now.. got some idea let see if works now. http://jsbin.com/kemoxabu/3/edit

Comment: Hi @Kheema Pandey, I've been trying to fiddle with this (http://jsfiddle.net/tousif123/TfhLb/) to possibly port it to my work. It works fine on IE. Pls, think you can help have quick look?

Comment: just a curious; did my recent DEMO link work for you? I've added these lines in your code.  `.nvbar li ul {
    position:absolute;
  display:none;
    top:30px;
}
.nvbar li:hover ul{
    position:absolute;
  display:block;
    top:30px;
}`

Comment: sadly, still doesn't work... feel like banging my head on the wall!

Comment: let me make it more simple for you.

Comment: it is just a simple CSS with simple HTML code use this in your code. and I hope your problem must be solved. http://jsbin.com/fineriqi/1/edit

Comment: final favor request, I'm a desktop application programmer and not really focused on web apps(hence the handicap). If you could comment sections in  (jsbin.com/fineriqi/1/edit) I'd probably be able to hack around and solve the problem. thanks

Comment: okay, made a comments on HTML section and put the exact CSS on your project. here is the updated link. http://jsbin.com/fineriqi/2/edit

Comment: let me know if that works for you, if yes then you might accept the answer.

Comment: I'd personally answer yes if i could considering the amount of time you've invested in assisting. But sadly it would be misleading if i said it worked. The solution is just an inhouse demo webapp, so i opted out of using a drop down menu.